# Всем привет, никак не могу понять, как сделать страницу как на фото, может кто помочь?

Tags: html, css, img

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как сделать страницу наполовину чёрного цвета и как добавить поверх цветов изображение+текст? (как на фото)

P.S.
Если это элементарно, то прошу не судить строго, я начинающий верстальщик.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставите блоку-родителю градиентный фон, а в дочернем блоке размещаете Вашу фотографию и надписи

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#fff 0 50%, #000 0 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border:  5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Примерно так выглядит:
[image: Внешний вид]

Блок с красными бордерами - дочерний

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, очень помогли! :)

Comment: Если Вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его галочкой, пожалуйста :)

Comment: ааа, я не знал об этом, отметил)